# Can't get my conditional to work inside a Playa field

Tags: playa, conditionals

I want to insert a simple exception, using an "if" statement, into the flow of my Playa field's output. But it's not working. Can I get help?

Here's the code that works:

```
{prac_area_contact_people backspace="3"}
<a href="/people/bios/{url_title}"><nobr>{exp:tagstripper:stripAllTags}{people_first_name} {person_last_name}{/exp:tagstripper:stripAllTags}</nobr></a>, 
{/prac_area_contact_people}
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

`prac_area_contact_people` is the name of my Playa field.

I want to add some content to the end of the anchor tag in the 2nd line of the sample above, ONLY when the `person_last_name` field is equal to a certain value.

So I did this:

```
<a href="/people/bios/{url_title}/{if person_last_name == 'pollack'}professional_liability{/if}">
```

The goal is that when the `person_last_name` field is `pollack` it adds on the extra segment in the URL. But the thing fails. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You're using `people` for the first name, but `person` for the last name - is that intentional, or a typo (and it that your problem)?

Comment: The field names for people_first_name and person_last_name are correct. Just inconsistent.

Comment: I fixed the problem that was preventing my code from showing up up where it says "So I did this..." It shows now!

Answer (score 0):

That should work as you have it, unless something else is parsing the conditional before Playa can get to it. Try using Playa’s `var_prefix` param to prevent that:

```
{prac_area_contact_people backspace="3" var_prefix="person"}
    <a href="/people/bios/{person:url_title}{person:if person_last_name == 'pollack'}/professional_liability{/person:if}">
        <nobr>{exp:tagstripper:stripAllTags}{person:people_first_name} {person_last_name}{/exp:tagstripper:stripAllTags}</nobr>
    </a>,
{/prac_area_contact_people}
```

Comment: Brandon, it doesn't work. How about if I change my approach, but excluding a single entry using the conditional in the following playa tag. I can just hard-code in the item I want at the end of the playa output. See here:

{prac_area_contact_people backspace="3" {if segment_2 == 'professional_liability'}entry_id="not 859"{/if}}
<a href="/people/bios/{url_title}"><nobr>{exp:tagstripper:stripAllTags}{people_first_name} {person_last_name}{/exp:tagstripper:stripAllTags}</nobr></a>, 
{/prac_area_contact_people}
{/exp:channel:entries}

But I tried this and entry 859 still shows in playa output.

Comment: ugh. the comments don't preserve my line breaks.

Comment: this is the line that I can't get to work, the if statement inside the playa tag. when i am on the page that has the segment 2 that it mentions, entry 859 is not excluded. {prac_area_contact_people backspace="3" {if segment_2 == 'professional_liability'}entry_id="not 859"{/if}}

Comment: Question withdrawn. I found a different strategy since this wasn't working. Thanks to those who lent a hand. I think I hate EE.

Answer (score 0):

The conditional you are looking for is as follow. You have to parse the variable into a string because of the parse order of the playa field.

{if "{prac_area_contact_people}" == "pollack"}
Content
{/if}

That should work.